# Betta fish fin rot or fin biting or fin injury?

Tags: diseases, betta

My betta has been suffering from what I thought was fin rot for a long time, progressively getting worse. Then, all of a sudden, today he dropped two full pieces of his fins (entire pie sliver chunks as shown in pictures).

I just started  medication treatment for fin rot as I thought this was the issue (and had been changing water for weeks prior), but I am now worried it could be fin biting, am I right? Or is it something getting caught in the tank?

Please advise me, thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although fin rot is prevalent, it is highly treatable. Medication such as Melafix and Aquarisol are usually added in the aquarium water to kill the bacteria that causes fin rot.

The best method to treat fin rot is to kill the harmful bacteria in your aquarium with a product like Melafix. I have been using Melafix for years with no adverse effects and with a very high success rate for treating the disease. It’s the gold standard of fish medication and should be sufficiently stocked in the cabinet of every aquarium owner.

And be sure to check the water parameters. Check the ammonia, nitrate, pH, chlorine (you can do it by buying an API test kit, it will enable you to test the pH levels in your water as often as needed!) Check the temperature, it should be around 75 to 80 °F (24 to 27 °C). Cycle the water often.

Hopefully this helps!